# Django and allowed_hosts again - error 400

Tags: python, django

At first - i'm not experienced user nor programmer/web admin, so please be kind to me :-)

I have a django/apache combination and port forward on my router and trying to reach webserver from external world. Internal IP is 192.168.1.44 and port is standard 80. External IP is 185.47.222.180 and port 2346. As you can try yourself, when http://185.47.222.180:2346/ is typed in a browser, Django returns error 400.

I was trying to set 185.47.222.180 and also 185.47.222.180:2346 in allowed_hosts in settings.py file, but result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart Apache when you added `185.47.222.180` to your allowed hosts?

Comment: Yes I did - there was a type mismatch error....problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your debug page, your ALLOWED_HOSTS is `['orangepione', 'localhost', '192.168.1.44', '187.47.222.180']` - it should be `['orangepione', 'localhost', '192.168.1.44', '185.47.222.180']` (you put **187**.47.222.180 instead of **185**.47.222.180)

Comment: OMFG! thank you so much, it was late night and I didn't see that obvious type mismatch.

Comment: This answer is right and it works now! If anyone is interested in my project, contact me via pm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add port to allowed hosts. Remove the port and it should work, or at least the error would change.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['185.47.222.180']  # not ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['185.47.222.180:2346']
```

Comment: I tried it without a port as the first solution, it did not work.

Comment: Why don't you run your apache on port 80?

Comment: There is another webserver on port 80 in my home network.